# Could a moderately complicated rails/django app serve 50 requests a second?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, web-applications

See the title :)

Comment: What would 'moderately complicated' mean in your situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the application complexity, hardware available, system structure, database structure, caching strategy and many many other factors. Twitter uses RoR for its frontend, and they get more than 50 requests/second.

Your question is very general and can not be answered within the parameters you specified.